# MKMapView not focusing in on CoreLocation

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, mkmapview, core-location

I am using MapView and CoreLocation in a simple iPhone app... the CoreLocation shows my latitude and longitude correctly:

```
[Session started at 2012-07-08 20:11:35 +0200.]
2012-07-08 20:11:37.082 WhereAmI[5095:207] <+52.37609766, +4.92279518> +/- 70.00m (speed    0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/8/12 8:11:33 PM Central European Summer Time
2012-07-08 20:11:38.605 WhereAmI[5095:207] <+52.37609766, +4.92279518> +/- 70.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/8/12 8:11:38 PM Central European Summer Time
```

However when I run:

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

The highlighted location is AppleHQ in California and not Amsterdam <+52.37609766, +4.92279518>?

From console logging I did find this "User location view is NOT visible" error:

```
2012-07-08 20:11:46.600 WhereAmI[5095:207] User location view is NOT visible but should be. Showing....
```

I did search on this and was advised to run:

```
mapView.userLocationVisible;
```

This executes ok but made no difference?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your Xcode you're not using a simulated location. Click on the arrow button in the debug bar (shown below) and select "Don't simulate location". On the attached picture the button you want is on the right.

**EDIT:** This answer applies to Xcode 4 and later only. There's no location simulation feature in Xcode 3.

[image: The button you want is on the right in this picture]

Comment: This sonds promising but the debugger in Xcode 3.2.5 looks different? I did check: 

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html

which suggested checking:  Product > Debug > Simulate Location menu.

but I suspect this is an Xcode 4 feature?

NB I will be upgrading to 10.8 soon (currently on 10.6)

Comment: You're right... I just looked and location simulation first appeared in Xcode 4. I thought you were using a recent version :)

Answer (score 0):

Running mapView.userLocationVisible but itself will do nothing. It gives you a value and you need to do something with it.

If the blue pin is showing up in California (the only place it will appear when using the simulator on older XCodes) and you're reading lat/longs in Amsterdam, then you'll need to show us how you are getting those lat/longs because iOS can't think it is in two places at once, you must have set one of them manually.

When it comes to setting the map view to look at your location, I would have advised UserTrackingMode, but if you're on XCode 3.x you're probably not on the latest iOS so try

```
- (void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or any of the related functions under the "Manipulating the visible portion of the map" section from the class reference
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html